# Call of overloaded 'ref(Select::Expressions::Code&)' is ambiguous in C++11

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, boost

## Background

---

I have a large program which needs to use a new version of a specific third
party library, which has recently been upgraded to require C++11 support (i.e.
compiled with GCC with `-std=c++11`). Additionally, some of the header files for this library apparently make use of C++11 syntax, so I need to upgrade the
entire application and its own in-house libraries to compile against a new GCC
(i.e. v4.8 or later) with `-std=c++11`.

The bulk of this work has been trivial, except for libraries that use boost. For legal reasons, I'm currently stuck with Boost 1.60.0, but can potentially change this. I built a new release of Boost 1.60.0, and ran into problems with `list_of`, which
I was able to resolve via:

[#7364 - ambiguity error constructing std::vector from
  assign::list_of](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/7364).

↪[#5419 - assign fails with C++0x
  compilers](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/5419).

↪[Ticket #5419: assign_cxx0x.patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/attachment/ticket/5419/assign_cxx0x.patch)

---

## Problem

---

This got me past the bulk of my compilation errors. Now, I seem to have one last
recurring thorn in my side, which is effectively a slew of:

```
note: std::reference_wrapper<_Tp> std::ref(_TP&) .... ref(_Tp& __t)
...
call of overloaded 'ref(Select::Expressions::Code&)' is ambiguous
```

And:

```
/opt/libboost_1.60.0/api/boost/phoenix/core/reference.hpp:69:5:
note: const typename boost::phoenix::expression::reference<T>::type
boost::phoenix::ref(T&) [with T = std::vector<long unsigned int>; typename
boost::phoenix::expression::reference<T>::type =
boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,
boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::reference_wrapper<std::vector<long unsigned
int> > >, 0l> >]
     ref(T & t)
call of overloaded 'ref(Select::Expressions::Code&)' is ambiguous
```

The only information I could find on this is a separate StackOverflow post
(which I can no longer find) which noted that C++11 introduces additional
default overloads, which is the likely/possible cause of this issue.

## Question

---

Is this something that can be resolved by:

- Patching boost?
- Upgrading boost to a newer version?
- Worst-case scenario, is there as simple change that can be uniformly applied to each instance of this error?

My primary goal is to get this building, without having to re-write and re-test a massive piece of boost-heavy code.

Comment: I think the current boost version is 1.64. IMHO you'd be wise to upgrade rather than worrying about bodging an old version to work. As of c++11, isn't boost::assign obsolete anyway?

Comment: @RichardHodges Assuming just migrating to boost 1.64.0 does the trick, are there any other caveats? I'll try that out, by the way. Thanks.

Comment: Is the code calling `ref` in Boost code, third party code, your code, or what?

Comment: @aschepler My own code (which I can change) is calling `ref`.

Comment: Which `ref` do you want to call? The `boost::phoenix` one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is a brand new function overload set in C++11.  (Not just additional overloads added; they're all new.)  From your error messages, it sounds like the argument type is both a `Select::Expressions::Code` and a `std::vector<long unsigned int>`, so `Code` must be a typedef for the `vector`.

There's no way to prevent the expression `ref(some_vec)` from finding `std::ref` as one of the overloads to consider.  Since the argument is really a `std::vector`, [Argument-Dependent Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) will always find `std::ref`.  `boost::phoenix::ref` also needs to be general enough to accept any lvalue argument, so there's no changing it to be a better match for overload resolution.

One option is to change all your `ref` calls to use a qualified name, so that Argument-Dependent Lookup does not apply.

```
boost::phoenix::ref(something)
```

Or maybe to make it shorter you could use a namespace alias:

```
namespace bp = boost::phoenix;
bp::ref(something)
```

Or if you have control of the typedef `Select::Expressions::Code` and an awful lot of uses of `ref`, and you just want to make the existing code work as quickly as possible, you could try this.  Spending a nasty bit of work but all in one place, you could change `Code` to a class that works almost exactly like the vector:

```
class Code {
public:
    using vec_type = std::vector<long unsigned int>;
#define CODE_TYPE(type) using type = vec_type::type
    CODE_TYPE(value_type);
    CODE_TYPE(allocator_type);
    CODE_TYPE(size_type);
    CODE_TYPE(difference_type);
    CODE_TYPE(reference);
    CODE_TYPE(const_reference);
    CODE_TYPE(pointer);
    CODE_TYPE(const_pointer);
    CODE_TYPE(iterator);
    CODE_TYPE(const_iterator);
    CODE_TYPE(reverse_iterator);
    CODE_TYPE(const_reverse_iterator);
#undef CODE_TYPE

    Code() noexcept(noexcept(vec_type())) {}
    Code(const Code&) = default;
    Code(Code&& c) noexcept(noexcept(vec_type(std::declval<vec_type&&>())))
        : m_v(std::move(c.m_v)) {}
    explicit Code(const allocator_type& a)
        noexcept(noexcept(vec_type(a))) : m_v(a) {}
    Code(size_type n, const value_type& val,
        const allocator_type& a=allocator_type()) : m_v(n, val, a) {}
    explicit Code(size_type n, const allocator_type& a=allocator_type())
        : m_v(n, a) {}
    template <class InputIt,
        class Enable=typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>
    Code(InputIt start, InputIt stop,
         const allocator_type& a=allocator_type())
        : m_v(start, stop, a) {}
    Code(const vec_type& v) : m_v(v) {}
    Code(const vec_type& v, const allocator_type& a) : m_v(v,a) {}
    Code(vec_type&& v) noexcept(noexcept(vec_type(std::move(v))))
        : m_v(std::move(v)) {}
    Code(vec_type&& v, const allocator_type& a)
        noexcept(noexcept(vec_type(std::move(v), a)))
        : m_v(std::move(v), a) {}
    Code(std::initializer_list<value_type> il,
         const allocator_type& a=allocator_type()) : m_v(il, a) {}

    Code& operator=(const Code&) = default;
    Code& operator=(Code&&) = default;
    Code& operator=(const vec_type& v) { m_v = v; return *this; }
    Code& operator=(vec_type&& v)
        noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<vec_type&>() =
                          std::declval<vec_type&&>()))
        { m_v = std::move(v); return *this; }

    vec_type& get() noexcept { return m_v; }
    const vec_type& get() const noexcept { return m_v; }
    operator vec_type&() noexcept { return m_v; }
    operator const vec_type&() const noexcept { return m_v; }

#define CODE_FUNC(name) \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) name(Args&& ...args) noexcept(noexcept( \
      std::declval<vec_type&>().name(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
    { return m_v.name(std::forward<Args>(args)...); } \
    template<typename ...Args> \
    decltype(auto) name(Args&& ...args) const noexcept(noexcept( \
      std::declval<const vec_type&>().name(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) \
    { return m_v.name(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

    CODE_FUNC(assign)
    CODE_FUNC(get_allocator)
    CODE_FUNC(at)
    CODE_FUNC(operator[])
    CODE_FUNC(front)
    CODE_FUNC(back)
    CODE_FUNC(data)
    CODE_FUNC(begin)
    CODE_FUNC(cbegin)
    CODE_FUNC(end)
    CODE_FUNC(cend)
    CODE_FUNC(rbegin)
    CODE_FUNC(crbegin)
    CODE_FUNC(rend)
    CODE_FUNC(crend)
    CODE_FUNC(empty)
    CODE_FUNC(size)
    CODE_FUNC(max_size)
    CODE_FUNC(reserve)
    CODE_FUNC(capacity)
    CODE_FUNC(shrink_to_fit)
    CODE_FUNC(clear)
    CODE_FUNC(insert)
    CODE_FUNC(emplace)
    CODE_FUNC(erase)
    CODE_FUNC(push_back)
    CODE_FUNC(emplace_back)
    CODE_FUNC(resize)
#undef CODE_FUNC

    void swap(Code& c) noexcept(noexcept(
        std::declval<vec_type&>().swap(std::declval<vec_type&>())))
    { m_v.swap(c.m_v); }
private:
    vec_type m_v;
};

#define CODE_OP(op) bool operator op(const Code& a, const Code& b) \
    noexcept(noexcept(a.get() op b.get())) { return a.get() op b.get(); }
CODE_OP(==)
CODE_OP(!=)
CODE_OP(<)
CODE_OP(>)
CODE_OP(<=)
CODE_OP(>=)
#undef CODE_OP

void swap(Code& a, Code& b) noexcept(noexcept(a.swap(b)))
{ a.swap(b); }
```

Since now `Code` is not a member of `namespace std`, it will no longer bring in `std::ref` for Argument-Dependent Lookup.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.